# Generar una imagen a partir de docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, lamp

Hola como puedo generar una imagen a  partir de `docker-compose.yml` , el script funciona, se crean el volumen, y todo pero necesito pasarloa a imagen par hacer un `push y pull` al otro lado.

Encontré por allí `docker build` pero este require de una `dockerfile` para construirlo, y yo generé todo via `docker-compose.yml`, eventualmente agregaré `php` por eso está en `docker-compose`, y generar todo en una única imagen, ¿Como hago eso?

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: db_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123456' # TODO: Change this
      MYSQL_USER: 'test'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'pass'
    volumes:
      - volume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306  
volumes:
  volume:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo que quieres es replicar los servicios que levantas con el `docker-compose.yml` en cualquier otra máquina simplemente tienes que compartir este archivo.

Comment: @E.Betanzos ese es el punto, no usar los códigos fuente,

Comment: Los archivos `docker-compose.yml` NO son código fuente de ningún tipo, son una especie de manifiesto de defines las configuraciones necesarias para desplegar tus contenedores. Este es el mismo enfoque que usan en los orquetadores (como Kubernetes) que son ampliamente utilizados en entornos críticos de producción, por lo que mi opinión es que lo corrector en este caso sería compartir el `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no estás obligado a compartir datos sensibles en el `docker-compose.yml`, ya que al final los parámetros que los emplean pueden ser modificados de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Comment: De todos modos puedes buscar un poco sobre "docker app bundle". Esto está en una etapa EXPERIMENTAL y creo que el concepto es lo que pides, pero NO DEBE ser usado en producción. Incluso no sé siquiera si llega a ver la luz ya  que desde la DockerCon del 2018 (si no me falla la memoria) se está hablando de esto y sigue en modo experimental.